# Getting null value for every field when trying to scrape. Scrapy, python

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Trying to crawl company names from https://www.adapt.io/directory/industry/telecommunications/A-1, and scrape data in the format,

[
{“company name”: “A & L Personnel Services”, “company_location”: “Gregory, Michigan”
"company_website": http://www.cac.net”, “company_webdomain”: “cac.net”,
“company_industry”: “Telecommunications”, “company_employee_size”:None,
“company_revenue” :None, “contact_details”: [{“contact_name”: “Doug Waite”,
“contact_jobtitle”: “owner”, “contact_email_domain”: “cac.net”, “contact_department”:
“Finance and Administration”},{“contact_name”: “Jim Mason”, “contact_jobtitle”: “Club
Directior”, “contact_email_domain”: “cac.net”, “contact_department”: “Other”}]},
…
]

But getting null value for every field.

```
import scrapy


class CompanyProfileSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'companyDetails'
  start_urls = ["https://www.adapt.io/directory/industry/telecommunications/A-1"]
  
  def parse(self, response):
    for company in response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'DirectoryList_linkItemWrapper__3F2UE ')]"):
      name = company.css('a::text').get()
      company_portal = company.css('a::attr(href)').get()
      
      if company_portal is not None:
        next_page = response.urljoin(company_portal)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.company_parse)

  def company_parse(self, response):
    block = response.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'CompanyTopInfo_infoValue__27_Yo')]")
    data = block.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'CompanyTopInfo_contentWrapper__2Jkic')]")
    output = {}
   # for i in data:
    #  output[i.css('span::text').get()] = i.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'CompanyTopInfo_infoValue__27_Yo')]").css('span::text').get()
    #yield{
     # 'company_data': output,
    #}

    company_employee = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'TopContacts_roundedBorder__1a3yB undefined')]")
    employee_url = company_employee.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'TopContacts_contactName__3N-_e')]").css('a::attr(href)').getall()
    for url in employee_url:
      if url is not None:
          next_page = response.urljoin(url)
          yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.employee)

  def employee(self, response):
    
    
    company_name=response.xpath( "//div[@class='info-wrapper']//h1//text()").get(),
    company_location =   response.xpath("//div[@class='info-wrapper']//li//span[text()='Location']//following-sibling::node()[2]/text()").get(),
    company_website =   response.xpath("//div[@class='info-wrapper']//span[@class='website-url']/text()").get(),
    company_industry= response.xpath("//div[@class='info-wrapper']//li//span[text()='Industry']//following-sibling::node()[2]/text()").get(),
    company_employee_size =  response.xpath("//div[@class='info-wrapper']//li//span[text()='Head Count']//following-sibling::node()[2]/text()").get(),
    company_revenue = response.xpath("//div[@class='info-wrapper']//li//span[text()='Revenue']//following-sibling::node()[2]/text()").get(),
    
    contact_items = response.xpath("//div[@class='top-contact-item']")
    contact_name = contact_items.xpath('.//a//text()').get(),
    contact_jobtitle =  contact_items.xpath(".//p[@class='contact-role']//text()").get(),
    email = response.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'ContactTopInfo_infoValue__DNIWM')]").css('span::text').get(),
    contact_department = response.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'ContactTopInfo_infoValue__DNIWM')]")[2].css('span::text').get()
    
    yield{
      'company_name':company_name,
      'company_location':  company_location,
      'company_website':  company_website,
      'company_industry': company_industry,
      'company_employee_size': company_employee_size,
      'company_revenue': company_revenue,
      
      'contact_details':[
        {
        'contact_name':contact_name,
        'contact_jobtitle': contact_jobtitle,
        'email':email,
        'contact_department':contact_department}
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Two issues with your code:

1. You have commas after `.get()`
2. You XPath expressions are not working anymore.

For example:

```
company_location =   response.xpath("normalize-space(//div[contains(@class, 'ContactTopInfo_companyDetailItem')]//span[text()='Location']/following-sibling::span[1])").get()
company_industry= response.xpath("normalize-space(//div[contains(@class, 'ContactTopInfo_companyDetailItem')]//span[text()='Industry']/following-sibling::span[1])").get()
```